# Position SlidingMenu above content (on tablet)

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am using the  jfeinstein10 / SlidingMenu (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), which works perfectly so far. When showing the menu on a Tablet, I would like that the sliding menu is always visible to the user.

Question: How can I make the menu visible above the content?

How it works now: When I swype right, the content is slided to right and the menu becomes visible.

How it should work: When I swype right, the content is left where it is and only the menu should overlap the content.

Comment: It's probably a better practice to use Google's implementation of this; the NavigationDrawer. Most Sliding Menu libraries, were made in a time where Google was indecisive about this kind of navigation and are probably deprecated since Google made its own.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having **toggle()** function, call this function in your activity's onCreate() function.

Comment: toggle() just makes the SlidingMenu open / close, hence when opening, the content is pushed out of the screen, making place for the menu. I would like that the content is not being touched at all and that the menu would be on top.